# Iteration, find

Tags: c++, string, iterator, iteration

Please help! How would i find and remove leading underscores by iterating through looking at the characters and counting the number of underscores before a valid character occurs. As well as iterating backwards from the end of the string to find any trailing underscores.

I can use the following method, to erase the underscore, but how would is iterate to find underscores.

```
resultF.erase(resultF.length()- trailingCount);
resultF.erase(0,leadingCount);
```

If user enters a string of **___twenty_three__**, the end result should be twenty_three. So only the leading and trailing underscore are deleted.

Comment: Leading (first char) and trailing (last char) only? You don't need to iterate over the entire string for that... (The hints are in the parens)

Comment: i've tried find_first_of,  and find_last_of, but these delete all the underscore.

Comment: The question did specify the potential of more than one underscore at (the first/last char) but that could be taken care of (while) their are searching.

Comment: I've tried  while(resultF[0] ==  '_') {
            resultF = resultF.substr(1);
         } , this works perfectly for the leading underscore.

Comment: Sorry about that Sam, if there are more than one leading and trialing underscores at, i will change the original post.

Comment: I was just being silly with Xeo. What failed with `while(resultF[0] == '_')`?  (I'm not near a compiler.)

Comment: The while(resultF[0] == '_'), didn't fail for the leading underscore, but i can't get the trailing underscore to be removed

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should use the string library's [find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) and [find_last_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_not_of/).  There are great code examples on those pages.

```
// From the links above: 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("erase trailing white-spaces   \n");
  string whitespaces (" \t\f\v\n\r");
  size_t found;

  found=str.find_last_not_of(whitespaces);
  if (found!=string::npos)
    str.erase(found+1);
  else
    str.clear();            // str is all whitespace

  cout << '"' << str << '"' << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1340113 Can you show us the code you used, using the links I showed you above (and some similar methods: find_last_of, find_last_not_of, find_first_of, find_first_not_of) I removed underscores from the beginning and end of a string just fine.  I know reading the documentation can be frustrating, but if you look through the methods I've shown you, and think about what you're trying to do, you should be able to figure this out.  Let me know how you're doing and I can update more.

Answer (score 1):

Something on these lines

```
string remove_(const string& str) {
  int i,j;
  int n = str.length();
  for(i=0;i < n && (str[i] != '_');i++);
  for(j=n;j > 0 && (str[j-1] != '_');j--);
   if(j <= i)
      return string(); //all underscores
  return ((str).substr(i,j-i));
}
```

Comment: Should take `str` by `const` reference, and what's `((str))(i, j-i)`?  Idea's right, but there's no substring functor facility in `std::string`.  Also, it's not necessarily bad, but this does return a new string rather than edit the original - that's generally less efficient.

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks for pointing it out i have edited to make it const and the typo of `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for leading characters:

```
std::string *str;
int ct = 0;

while(*str != '_'){
str++;
ct++;
}

For trailing characters:

while (* (str+length) != '_') {
str--;
ct++;
}
```